# Is there a way to interactively create a new Datastore entity kind for Go GAE apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to create a new Datastore entity kind via some interactive means for Go App Engine apps? The datastore viewer won't let me add new entity kinds, and the interactive console doesn't seem to support Go.

I'm trying to upload some configuration data to datastore, including sensitive data that I don't want to appear in code. So far the best method I can come up with is to write some code to write an empty configuration entity, deploy, run, then use the datastore viewer to set the values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can add new Entity Kinds in the Console.

In the Cloud Console, Click on the Datastore menu item, then 'Create an Entity'. [Handy link, just select your project name](https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/new?project=_)

Then in the Kind field, just type in your desired Kind name.

[image: Create an entity page showing a new kind name]

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is safe at AppEngine - nobody can download it. At least nobody outside of Google. You can deploy it to a dedicated version/module and restrict usage to yourself (check current user, ask pass-phrase, etc in your code).

Second you can **use [Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/remoteapi)** - this way you do not upload any code to AppEngine. You can create entities remotely as you wish using secure HTTPS connection.